# First of Two Decimal Fields Causes Exception When Fetched

Tags: c#, odbc, informix, decimalformat

I have an application written in C#, which uses *OdbcConnection*, *OdbcCommand*, and *OdbcDataReader*. 
The query is run against an Informix SE database running on a Linux system.

Within the query, at ordinal positions 27 and 28 (indexes 26 and 27), I attempt to fetch the latitude and longitude stored in each water meter record.

Here are the lat/long for the first of 12K+ accounts on which the first value fails with an invalid cast exception when read with dbReader.GetDecimal(

```
     geo_lat          geo_lon
```

42.4236953219   -71.1752100161

The first field to be fetched is GetDecimal(26), and it throws an invalid cast exception.

```
//  Type x = dbReader.GetFieldType(iReadIdx); after
//  testing, it's found to be a decimal.

decimal x = dbReader.GetDecimal(iReadIdx);
retStr = x.ToString();
```

Please note the commented out code was run to determine that index 26 was truly a decimal. I did think about whether the ordinals were wrong. They were not.

The only thing I can see is the latitude is a positive number, and the longitude is a negative number.

If I have to, I can make up a temporary table to map a string version of the latitude, which is what I want anyway, the latitude in a string.

Any ideas on how to further debug this problem would be appreciated.

Answers to Comments:

I have tried the following, which throws an exception.

`decimal x = decimal.Parse(dbReader.GetString(iReadIdx));`

But this does not, but it does not read the full decimal value either.

```
decimal x = decimal.Parse(dbReader.GetInt32(iReadIdx).ToString());
retStr = x.ToString();
break;
```

I would understand if the negative value did not fetch correctly, but not the positive value.

However, the second call fails using reading it as a string. I'll have to come up with some kludge.
Answers to questions recently asked:

My workaround is to have written a separate query, using the same OdbcConnection as the main query. Selecting only the lat/long decimal(15,10) values, these fetch perfectly.

This is the version of Informix on our Linux server, which is running SE, and not much is changing for Informix SE.

```
[ics@steamboy ics_client]$ esql -V
IBM Informix CSDK Version 3.00, IBM Informix-ESQL Version 3.00.UC3DE
Software Serial Number AAA#B000000
[ics@steamboy ics_client]$
```

Here is the main select, containing the fields geo_lat and geo_lon. It is GetDecimal(26) for geo_lat that throws an invalid cast exception. Please note  folio (selected before geo_lat) is a *smallint*, and I could read just the whole number part using *GetInt32(26)*.

```
string meterQ       =   
"select m.acct_no, "        + //1
"       m.suffix,  "        + //2
"       m.reg_no,  "        + //3
"       w.service, "        + //4
"       m.property_type, "  + //5
"       w.mtr_addr_no,  "   + //6
"       w.mtr_addr_str, "   + //7
"       w.mtr_addr_apt, "   + //8
"       w.owner_city, "     + //9
"       w.owner_state, "    + //10
"       w.owner_zip, "      + //11
"       w.owner_name_1, "   + //12
"       w.owner_name_2, "   + //13
"       w.owner_addr_1, "   + //14
"       w.owner_addr_2, "   + //15
"       w.re_acct,       "  + //16
"       m.meter_type,   "   + //17
"       m.meter_num,    "   + //18
"       m.date_installed, " + //19
"       m.numdigits,    "   + //20
"       w.billed_or_not, "  + //21
"       m.meter_size,   "   + //22
"       m.arb_no, "         + //23
"       m.read_instr, "     + //24
"       m.book, "           + //25
"       m.folio, "          + //26
"       m.geo_lat, "        + //27
"       m.geo_lon, "        + //28 
// cmn 4/24/2020 lat Lon fetched by separate query.
"       m.devicetype, "     + //29
"       m.channel,      "   + //30
"       w.same_re_addr "    + //31
"from   water w ,  meter m " +
"where  w.acct_no = m.acct_no " +
"and    m.last_update >= '" + cutoffDateP + "' " +
"and        m.meter_type != 'FS' "       +
"and        w.last_update is not null   "  +
"order by m.acct_no asc, m.suffix asc ";
```

Comment: Can you please check the value of `dbReader.GetString(iReadIdx);`? According to the source code of [OdbcDataReader](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/Odbc/OdbcDataReader.cs) the value for numeric and decimal types are read as a string first and then converted to decimal using `Decimal.Parse`

Comment: @OguzOzgul Did as you suggested. Still threw an exception.Unable to cast type Int32 to String.

Comment: Do you know which version of the Informix ODBC driver you are using, by any chance?  Do you know which version of the Informix server you are using?  Is this all running on Windows, or do you have a Unix-based Informix server (or, perhaps, Unix-based C#)?

Answer (score 1):

I am using .NET Framework 4.7 to compile the below program.

I tried below simple program with Informix database using CSDK/ODBC version 4.50.FC3 (Windows 64-bit) and it works perfectly.

Could you also share the version of Informix CSDK/ODBC you are using (output of "esql -V")?

Output of the below program as follows:

```
 **** Starting of Decimal Testcase ****
 **** Connected ****
create temp table mytable (intcol int, deccol1 decimal(20,10), deccol2 decimal(20,10));
 Table mytable created
insert into mytable values(1,'42.4236953219', '-71.1752100161');
 INSERT 1 rows
select * from mytable;
intcol = 1
deccol1 = 42.4236953219
deccol2 = -71.1752100161
 **** End of Decimal Testcase ****

Program:
--------
>using System;
>using System.Data;
>using System.Data.Odbc;
>using System.Text;
>
>public class OdbcDecimal
>{
>    static void Main(string[] args) 
>    {
>        int insrow = 0;
>        try 
>        {
>            string connectionString = "DSN=InformixDSN";
>            
>            try 
>            {
>                Console.WriteLine(" **** Starting of Decimal Testcase ****");
>                using (OdbcConnection conn0 = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
>                {
>                    conn0.Open();
>                    Console.WriteLine(" **** Connected ****");
>                    using (OdbcCommand cmd0 = conn0.CreateCommand())
>                    {
>                        try
>                        {
>                            cmd0.CommandText = "drop table mytable;";
>                            //Console.WriteLine(cmd0.CommandText);
>                            cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
>                            //Console.WriteLine(" Table mytable dropped");
>                        }
>                        catch { }
>
>                        cmd0.CommandText = "create table mytable (intcol int, deccol1 >decimal(20,10), deccol2 decimal(20,10));";
>                        Console.WriteLine(cmd0.CommandText);
>                        cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
>                        Console.WriteLine(" Table mytable created");
>                        
>                        cmd0.CommandText = "insert into mytable values(1,'42.4236953219', >'-71.1752100161');";
>                        Console.WriteLine(cmd0.CommandText);
>                        insrow = cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
>                        Console.WriteLine(" INSERT " + insrow + " rows");
>                        
>                        cmd0.CommandText = "select * from mytable;";
>                        Console.WriteLine(cmd0.CommandText);
>
>                        OdbcDataReader dr = null;
>                        Int32 vid = 0;
>                        decimal x;
>                        decimal y;
>                        
>                        dr = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
>                        while (dr.Read())
>                        {
>                            try
>                            {
>                                if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
>                                {
>                                    vid = dr.GetInt32(0);
>                                    Console.WriteLine("intcol = " + vid + " ");
>                                }
>                                else
>                                {
>                                    Console.WriteLine("intcol = null ");
>                                }
>
>                                if (!dr.IsDBNull(1))
>                                {
>                                    x = dr.GetDecimal(1);
>                                    Console.WriteLine("deccol1 = " + x.ToString() + " ");
>                                }
>                                else
>                                {
>                                    Console.WriteLine("deccol1 = null  ");
>                                }
>
>                                if (!dr.IsDBNull(2))
>                                {
>                                    y = dr.GetDecimal(2);
>                                    Console.WriteLine("deccol2 = " + y.ToString() + " ");
>                                }
>                                else
>                                {
>                                    Console.WriteLine("deccol2 = null ");
>                                }
>                            }
>                            catch (OverflowException exc)                      
>                            {                                                  
>                                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
>                            }
>                        }
>                        dr.Close();
>                          
>                    }
>                }         
>             } 
>             catch (OdbcException ioe) 
>             { 
>                Console.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
>               Console.WriteLine(ioe.StackTrace);
>             } 
>        }
>        catch (Exception ex)
>        {
>            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
>            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
>        }
>        Console.WriteLine(" **** End of Decimal Testcase ****");
>    } 
>}
```

Comment: Edited OP to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share version of System.Data.dll/System.Data.Odbc.dll (depending on which verison of Framework you are using, System.Data.Odbc.dll could be part of System.Data.dll itself)?

Also, could you try the program which I shared? This is self sufficient test case, this will confirm the issue, since we are trying exact same test case in our respective environments.